# Product of Consecutive Integers is Not a Power

Tags: number-theory

Is it true that the product of $n>1$ consecutive integers is never a $k$-th power of another integer for any $k \geq 2$?

I can see this is true in certain cases. For instance if the product ends on a prime, But how would one prove this in general?

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, this is true. This was proven by Erdős and Selfridge in [this paper](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1975-46.pdf).

Comment: Well, that wasn't the short proof I was expecting.

Comment: @Carl, whatever made you expect a short proof?

Comment: @Gerry; Because I'm quite stupid.

Comment: @Carl, cheer up, we're all quite stupid - that's why we're here.

Comment: @Gerry; Actually, the miserable people I know are all quite smart.

Comment: @CarlBrannen - "He who learns must suffer. And even in our sleep pain that cannot forget falls drop by drop upon the heart, and in our own despair, against our will, comes wisdom to us by the awful grace of God." -- Aeschylus