# A question on primes and equal products

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers

Is the following statement true;
"For any odd prime number $p$ , any set of $p-1$ consecutive integers can not be  partitioned into two subsets such that the elements of the two sets have equal product." ( I think I read somewhere that Erdos proved it but now I can not remember where I read so , I can only prove the statement for prime of the form $ 4k+3$ , any complete solution or link would be very helpful)

Comment: Isn't it true more generally that the product of (any number of) consecutive integers can't be a square? can't be a $k$th power for any $k\ge2$?

Comment: No, but I've given you a link. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33338/product-of-consecutive-integers-is-not-a-power

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erdos and Selfridge, [The product of consecutive integers is never a power](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-19/issue-2/The-product-of-consecutive-integers-is-never-a-power/10.1215/ijm/1256050816.full), Illinois J Math 19 (1975) 292-301.